# No corect response from server:Content type 'null' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I get the error "Content type 'null' not supported 415" when i try to send GET request of json object with some parameters from postman whereas, I should get an id of that object from server side after receving the json object.

UserController:

```
package com.nust.QuizApplication.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.nust.QuizApplication.dao.UserDAO;
import com.nust.QuizApplication.model.User;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup" ,method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json" )
    @ResponseBody
    public int create(@RequestBody User user) {
        int id = userDao.signupUser(user);
        if(id>0)
            return id;
        else
            return 0;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin",method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json" )
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean signinUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        boolean check = userDao.signinUser(user);
        if(check==true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the Content-type of the request header to application/json in postman?

Comment: Yes. Should i specify get and post, both in the controller?@FRowe

Comment: It is more typical to use POST for object creation.  Verify that you're sending a valid json object in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestBody` For GET method.
like

```
 public boolean signinUser(@RequestParam(value = "user", required = true) User user)
```